# Replace specific color in CGBitmapContext

Tags: ios, colors, cgcontext, cgcontextref, cgbitmapcontext

How can I replace specific color(RGB value) in `CGBitmapContext` that has already drawn?

Is there any easy way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "a specific color". Do you mean an exact RGB value, such as (15, 137, 219)? Or do you mean in the colloquial sense of "green" or "yellow" or whatever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to get a pointer to the pixels and information about their format by doing something like this:

```
// This assumes the data is RGBA format, 8-bits per channel. 
// You'll need to verify that by calling CGBitmapContextGetBitsPerPixel (), etc.
typedef struct RGBA8 {
    UInt8 red;
    UInt8 green;
    UInt8 blue;
    UInt8 alpha;
} RGBA8;

RGBA8* pixels = CGBitmapContextGetData (context);
UInt32 height = CGBitmapContextGetHeight (context);
UInt32 width = CGBitmapContextGetWidth (context);
UInt32 rowBytes = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow (context);
UInt32 x, y;
for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    RGBA8* currentRow = (RGBA8*)((UInt8*)pixels + y * rowBytes);
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        if ((currentRow->red == replaceRed) && (currentRow->green == replaceGreen) &&
            (currentRow->blue == replaceBlue) && (currentRow->alpha == replaceAlpha))
        {
            currentRow->red = newRed;
            currentRow->green = newGreen;
            currentRow->blue = newBlue;
            currentRow->alpha = newAlpha;
        }
        currentRow++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Multiply each channel by 255. So it would be (R,G,B,A) = (222, 138, 103, 255).